# Jenkins Multibranch pipeline branchname suffix

Tags: git, jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I have the following problem with jenkins, which might be possible lack of understanding/knowledge or it could be duplicate question because I do not really know what to search for or where to search for the info.

The scenario:

I'm having a dockerized jenkins setup for my development, where I created multiple pipeline/projects in.

I have a multibranch project `example-multibranch-project` which is a git repository with the branches `main` and `feature/XY`*.

Within the jenkins instance I can now see my project with its branches, but when I have a look to the filesystem that hosts the jenkins instance I can see the following output from `tree`:

```
├── example-multibranch-project
│   └── branches
│       ├── main
│       │   └── builds
│       │       └── 1
│       │           └── workflow
│       └── feature-XY.b78nl1
│           └── builds
│               └── 1
│                   └── workflow
```

Now the question for me is:

Where does the suffix `.b78nl1` come from and how can this be avoided or marked?
Because when removing this suffix the artifacts won't be shown in Jenkins anymore.
Another thing is when using an external storage (e.g. minio) for the artifacts the "wrong" branch naming might lead to errors with the visualization of the artifacts since the folder in `minio` would be named `feature-XY.b78nl1` which is not the correct name and therefore can't be resolved.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

- *the branch is named with a dot or slash, which I reversed during research on this topic/question

Comment: Is this SO question related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755038/ssl-problems-with-s3-aws-using-the-java-api-hostname-in-certificate-didnt-mat the matching issue in the Jenkins issue tracker: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-54865

Comment: Not quite the right thing, but thanks a lot since this brought me closer to what I currently think the source of the problem is: Jenkins seems to add this Suffix for `multibranch pipelines` where the branchname contains either `/` or `.`. This means `feature-XY.b78nl1` is a git branch that is originally named either `feature.XY` or `feature/XY` within the git repo.